# How to combine video source with audio?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, plyr

Now I want to combine video and audio source
I get sources from youtube with https://github.com/Athlon1600/youtube-downloader

my output :
[image]

then i use Plyr.io to play video
[image]

and I used a lot of solutions
like popcorn js from https://tackoverflow.com/questions/6433900/syncing-html5-video-with-audio-playback
and didn't work successfully

my code [image]

I used a video tag for the audio source and hide it

The problem is there's a lot of bugs and don't work perfectly
now I want to use a player like youtube or any js code to make this process like youtube

another question: there's a way to stream audio and video together with PHP
like this code https://github.com/Athlon1600/youtube-downloader/blob/34de92b550cd72be3e31902ce62a3bbc19714118/src/YouTubeStreamer.php#L61

but it's streaming a single source, there's a way to combine audio and video and stream it together LIVE without FFmpeg

Comment: ffmpeg is the tool. there's no reason you can't play 2 media files concurrently with JS though if you must. in fact it does that by default. just `.play()` them at the same time.

Comment: Don't post codes as screenshot. Please paste and format your code in your question (edit it).

Comment: @RonnieRoyston can i use blob ? like this http://plnkr.co/edit/r51oh7KsZv8DEYhpRJlL?p=preview&preview
but this code cach and download all file then combine it in blob

and .play() don't work successfully becouse there's a seeking and a lot of events effiect on audio player

Comment: @Raptor this codes not important and too long becouse urls 
so i used screenshots to preview a tags and code format

Answer (score 0):

```js
var video = document.getElementById('dsp_video_');
var audio = document.getElementById('dsp_audio_');
syncIntervalVideo = setInterval(function(){
    audio.playbackRate = video.playbackRate; //Speed
    audio.volume = video.volume;
    audio.currentTime = video.currentTime;
    video.paused ? audio.pause() : audio.play();
    video.muted == true ? audio.muted = true : audio.muted = false;
}, 500);
```